# Using built in sort function multiple times causes Runtime-error: '1004' The sort reference is not valid

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that involves sorting different columns at different points in the same sheet. When I try to run the sort function more than once I get the following error:

"Runtime-error '1004' The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."

As far as I can tell from the code and the data in the sheet, both the  criteria from the error are met.

These are two of the sorts I need to perform, and if I run the macro with just one, either will work, but if I use both, the second sort will fail.

```
Worksheets("Overview").Range("A1").Sort key1:=Worksheets("Overview").Range("AC1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

```
Worksheets("Overview").Range("A1").Sort key1:=Worksheets("Overview").Range("BY1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified wrong range for the sort function.

```
Worksheets("Overview").Range("A1").Sort
```

The above code tells the sort function only to sort one cell, A1. You need to specify the range e.g. .Range("A1:A100").

Comment: Sadly I have tried this, in my case with `.Range(A1:A1000).Sort` and it does not solve the problem.